# How to write Junit test cases for Java class in AEM6.2

Tags: junit, aem

I need to write JUnit Test cases for Java classes which are being used for business logic and interact with AEM. I don't find the proper document for writing JUnit test cases.If you have any such document , request you to share with me.

Comment: Check this Link, very useful for beginners : http://www.wemblog.com/2016/12/how-to-write-tests-in-aem.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for here. The Junit test cases for AEM classes are no different that what you write of any Java class. You may need a mocking framework to Mock the Sling objects if need be.

The details around mocking for OSGI and sling classes are described on apache sling site [here](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/testing-sling-based-applications.html#mock-classes-and-services) with the sample code in [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/bundles/commons/testing)

A sample WCMUsePojo Class -

```
public class DisplayAsDataSourceWcmUse extends WCMUsePojo {


    /**
     * Display as script regex.
     */
    private static final String DISPLAY_AS_REGEX_EXPR = "^displayAs\\_(.*)\\.html$";

    /**
     * Datasource to the display listing.
     */
    private DataSource dataSource;

    /**
     * activate method.
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("PMD.SignatureDeclareThrowsException")
    @Override
    public final void activate() throws Exception {
        this.buildDisplayAsOptions();
    }

    /**
     * Build the list of views for the DisplayAs Option.
     */
    private void buildDisplayAsOptions() {
        final SlingHttpServletRequest request = getRequest();
        final Resource componentResource = getCurrentComponent();
        List<Resource> resourceList = Collections.emptyList();

        if (null != componentResource) {
            final Iterable<Resource> children = () -> componentResource.listChildren();
            final Stream<Resource> childResourceStream = StreamSupport.stream(children.spliterator(), false);

            resourceList = childResourceStream
                    .filter(resource -> resource
                            .getName().matches(DISPLAY_AS_REGEX_EXPR))
                    .map(this::getMappedResource)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            childResourceStream.close();
        }

        if (resourceList.isEmpty()) {
            dataSource = EmptyDataSource.instance();
        } else {
            dataSource = new SimpleDataSource(resourceList.iterator());
        }

        // place it in request for consumption by datasource mechanism
        request.setAttribute(DataSource.class.getName(), dataSource);

    }

    /**
     * Get resource instance of current component i.e. resource with path to component under apps/.
     *
     * @return component resource.
     */
    private Resource getCurrentComponent() {
        final Resource listResource = getResourceResolver().getResource((String) getRequest().getAttribute(Value
                .CONTENTPATH_ATTRIBUTE));
        if (listResource != null) {
            return getResourceResolver().getResource(listResource.getResourceType());
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get Mapped Synthetic resource corresponding to the Display View.
     *
     * @param resource - Resource instance of display script.
     * @return ValueMapResource transformation of display script.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private ValueMapResource getMappedResource(final Resource resource) {
        final String value = resource.getName().replaceFirst(DISPLAY_AS_REGEX_EXPR, "$1");

        // see if there's a better label
        final String text = ResourceUtil.getValueMap(resource).get(JcrConstants.JCR_TITLE, value);

        // create a ValueMap
        final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
        map.put("text", text);
        map.put("value", value);

        // return a synthetic resource
        return new ValueMapResource(getResourceResolver(), new ResourceMetadata(), "", new ValueMapDecorator(map));

    }

    /**
     * Getter for dataSource.
     *
     * @return Datasource.
     */
    public final DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

One possible way to Unit Test using Mockito (not very ideal way,as you end up writing up lot of mocks, in such cases Integration Tests are best suited) -

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DisplayAsDataSourceWcmUseTest {

    @Mock
    private Bindings bindings;
    @Mock
    private Resource currentResource;
    @Mock
    private Resource componentResource;
    @Mock
    private ResourceResolver resourceResolver;
    @Mock
    private SlingHttpServletRequest request;
    @Mock
    private Iterator<Resource> childItr;
    @Mock
    private Resource displayAsOne;
    @Mock
    private Resource displayAsTwo;

    @InjectMocks
    private DisplayAsDataSourceWcmUse displayAsDataSourceWcmUse;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        when(bindings.get("resource")).thenReturn(currentResource);
        when(bindings.get("request")).thenReturn(request);
        when(request.getResourceResolver()).thenReturn(resourceResolver);
        when(request.getAttribute(Value.CONTENTPATH_ATTRIBUTE)).thenReturn("list/component/instance");

        when(currentResource.getResourceType()).thenReturn("current/resource/type");
        when(resourceResolver.getResource("current/resource/type")).thenReturn(componentResource);
        when(resourceResolver.getResource("list/component/instance")).thenReturn(currentResource);

        List<Resource> childRes = new ArrayList<>();
        childRes.add(displayAsOne);
        childRes.add(displayAsTwo);

        when(componentResource.listChildren()).thenReturn(childRes.iterator());
        when(displayAsOne.getName()).thenReturn("displayAs_One.html");
        when(displayAsTwo.getName()).thenReturn("displayAs_Two.html");

        Map<String, Object> vm1 = new HashMap();
        vm1.put(JcrConstants.JCR_TITLE, "Display Type One");

        when(displayAsOne.getValueMap()).thenReturn(new ValueMapDecorator(vm1));
        when(displayAsTwo.getValueMap()).thenReturn(new ValueMapDecorator(new HashMap()));

    }

    @Test
    public void test_display_option_are_set() throws Exception{
        displayAsDataSourceWcmUse = new DisplayAsDataSourceWcmUse();
        displayAsDataSourceWcmUse.init(bindings);

        assertTrue(displayAsDataSourceWcmUse.getDataSource() instanceof SimpleDataSource);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_empty_datasource_is_set() throws Exception{

        List<Resource> childRes = new ArrayList<>();
        when(componentResource.listChildren()).thenReturn(childRes.iterator());

        displayAsDataSourceWcmUse = new DisplayAsDataSourceWcmUse();
        displayAsDataSourceWcmUse.init(bindings);

        assertTrue(displayAsDataSourceWcmUse.getDataSource() instanceof EmptyDataSource);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at  ['ContiPerf 2'](http://databene.org/contiperf) .

ContiPerf is a lightweight testing utility that enables the user to easily leverage JUnit 4 test cases as performance tests e.g. for continuous performance testing. It is inspired by JUnit 4's easy test configuration with annotations and by JUnitPerf's idea of wrapping Unit tests for performance testing, but more powerful and easier to use:

- Using Java annotations for defining test execution characterisitics and performance requirements.
- You can mark a test to run a certain number of times or to be repeatedly executed for a certain amount of time.
- Performance requirements can be maximum, average, medium or any percentile exectution time.
- Perfect control and readability of performance requirements You can run tests in two different modes, using them as simple unit tests or performance tests.
- Easy integration with Eclipse and Maven.
- Export of execution summary to a CSV file.
- Small library without external dependencies (only JUnit).
- Easy extension with custom statistics evaluation and tracking mechanisms.